# Access android assets from XML

Tags: android, image, assets

I have lots of images in my Android app and was trying to get them organized in folders under the assets directory as opposed to having them all site in the drawable directory.

My question is how can I access the assets directory through XML.  For instance:

```
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_team_logo" 
            android:src="/assets/teamlogos/ARI" 
            android:layout_height="25dp" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
            android:layout_width="296dp" android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

Does not work.  Is there something I can put in the src string to make this work?  Or are assets only accessible using the AssetManager in code.

Comment: I don't think you can use the assets directory for that... assets is for jars and stuff like that. The lack of directories inside drawables is annoying but can be minimized with names. Ex: activityxpto_bed_image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you put your Images in the "drawable"-Recourse folder? That's where they belong. Those pictures can then be accessed in XML using something like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_file"
 />
```

Files located in the "assets"-Folder are accessed with the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html), which returns an InputStream on the desired File. I don't know any way of accessing them through XML.

Comment: The drawable folder doesnt allow subfolders and I was trying to managing my assets in a way so it isnt a shit show....But it sounds like Android expects you to just have 100s of images all in the same directory...

Comment: Yep, on larger Projects, this sucks. You could think of a system to name your Pictures in the drawable folder... Also notice, that there are four types of drawable-folders out there: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers